# Is there a way to delete a github workflow

Tags: github, github-api, github-actions

So I tried to put a `docker-compose.yml` file in the `.github/workflows` directory, of course it tried to pick that up and run it... which didn't work. However now this always shows up as a workflow, is there any way to delete it?

Comment: No. This is not currently possible.

Comment: @xenoterracide, I can confirm that the answer from HUAN XIE works.

Answer (score 3):

To delete a particular workflow on your *Actions* page, you need to delete all runs which belong to this workflow. Otherwise, it persists even if you have deleted the YAML file that had triggered it.

If you have just a couple of runs in a particular action, it's easier to delete them manually. But if you have a hundred runs, it might be worth running a simple script. For example, the following `python` script uses GitHub API:

Before you start, you need to install the `PyGithub` package (like `pip install PyGithub`) and define three things:

1. [PAT](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token): create a new personal access GitHub token;
2. your repo name
3. your action name (even if you got deleted it already, just hover over the action on the actions page):

```py
from github import Github
import requests

token = "ghp_1234567890abcdefghij1234567890123456" # your PAT
repo = "octocat/my_repo"
action = "my_action.yml"

g = Github(token)
headers = {'Accept': 'application/vnd.github.v3',
           'Authorization': f'token {token}'}

for run in g.get_repo(repo).get_workflow(id_or_file_name=action).get_runs():
    response = requests.delete(url=run.url, headers=headers)
    if response.status_code == 204:
        print(f"Run {run.id} got deleted")
```

After all the runs are deleted, the workflow automatically disappears from the page.

Comment: Don't forget to run pip install PyGithub upfront. Other than that it works very smoothly. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can delete the results of a run. See the documentation for [details](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/managing-workflow-runs/deleting-a-workflow-run).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can delete all the workflow runs in the workflow which you want to delete, then this workflow will disappear.

Comment: This was not obvious, but very helpful. I just deleted all the workflow runs and the workflow no longer existed in the GitHub Actions section of my repo.

Comment: I had also previously deleted the YAML file associated with the workflow in .github/workflows/ and made sure this file was no longer in the repo.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/actions#delete-a-workflow-run

To delete programmatically

Example (from the docs)

```sh
curl \
  -X DELETE \
  -H "Authorization: token <PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN>"
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
  https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/hello-world/actions/runs/42
```

Answer (score 0):

GitHub cli

> GitHub Actions/Manage workflow runs/[Deleting a workflow run](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/actions/workflow-runs?apiVersion=2022-11-28#delete-workflow-run-logs)

```
# GitHub CLI api
# https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_api

gh api \
  --method DELETE \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
  -H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28" \
  /repos/OWNER/REPO/actions/runs/RUN_ID/logs
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).