# How to delete GitHub Pages Workflow

Tags: github, github-actions, github-pages

I created a GitHub Pages site and with it a default pages-build-deployment workflow. Since there is no obvious way to configure this default workflow and this workflow by default uses Jekyll, I created a custom workflow to build my page with Hugo based on the template workflow for Hugo. However, every time I commit to my pages branch, both workflows are triggered and run. Which of those runs will eventually persist appears to be happenstance.

Since Jekyll cannot render my page in any meaningful way, I want to delete this default workflow. As proposed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71412216/2989330) answer, I deleted all workflow runs of the default workflow, but it keeps reappearing every time I commit to the branch. The GitHub docs on [creating custom workflows](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/using-custom-workflows-with-github-pages) and [deleting workflow runs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/managing-workflow-runs/deleting-a-workflow-run) also don't address this issue.

Comment: Take a look at .github folder please.

Comment: The .github folder contains my manually created workflow and nothing else.

Comment: Just went through the documentation, and it seems that your only option right now is to contact GitHub support. They should be able to remove that default branch based workflow for you from the backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your project page enter `Settings` tab. On the left hand side open `Pages`. Under `Build and deployment` change `Source` to `GitHub Actions`

Comment: OK, this in fact did the trick. Thank you very much!